# I am not able to retrieve the data in my service when my application closes

Tags: java, android

I have a Service that runs all the time in background even when the application is closed. I am passing some data from the activity where I started the service and i am retrieving it in `onStartCommand()`

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            tstatus=extras.getString("status");
            name=extras.getString("name");
            dl_no=extras.getString("dl");
            truck_id=extras.getString("tid");
            latitude=extras.getString("lat");
            longitude=extras.getString("lon");

        }
```

But the problem is when the application is in foreground or minimized it works fine but when I close the application my service not able to retrieve data I get following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.grobomac.driver.CameraService@2ea3e490 with null:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.grobomac.driver.CameraService.onStartCommand(CameraService.java:176)
```

Comment: the strings you are getting from extras same everytime?

Comment: From [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)): `Intent`: The Intent supplied to `startService(Intent)`, as given. This may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away

Comment: Because your activity is destroyed and you cannot receive intent from your activity.

Comment: No its not the same@AbdulWaheed

Comment: Can i retrieve the strings in oncreate method of the Service.